# Compute $\vec\nabla^2 \frac{1}{\mid \vec x \mid}$

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, laplacian

Compute $\vec\nabla^2 \frac{1}{\| \vec x \|}$ where $\vec x= x\hat i + y \hat j +z\hat k$

I have that $$\frac{1}{\| \vec x \|} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

So it follows that $\vec\nabla\frac{1}{\| \vec x \|}= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\| \vec x  \|^2\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(2x\hat i + 2y\hat j + 2z \hat k)$

At this point I do not know if this is right or how to continue.

What would $\vec\nabla^2\frac{1}{\| \vec x \|} $ be?

Comment: It [won't be a function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.2567.pdf).

Comment: As for $\nabla^2$, it is a shorthand for $\text{div}\,\text{grad}$.  I.e. $$\nabla^2 f = \nabla \cdot (\nabla f)$$

Comment: The advised approach for this solution is going to be the long, slow way. Consider working this problem in spherical coordinates with the appropriate laplacian. Also @Bye_World is leading you to the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x^2+y^2+z^2$, so we have:

$$
f(x,y,z)=u^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$
and:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{2}u^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot 2x=-xu^{-\frac{3}{2}}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-u^{-\frac{3}{2}}+x\cdot \frac{3}{2}u^{-\frac{5}{2}}\cdot 2x=-u^{-\frac{3}{2}}+3x^2u^{-\frac{5}{2}}
$$
By symmetry we have, in the same way:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=-u^{-\frac{3}{2}}+3y^2u^{-\frac{5}{2}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}=-u^{-\frac{3}{2}}+3z^2u^{-\frac{5}{2}}
$$

so:
$$
\nabla^2f= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}=-3u^{-\frac{3}{2}}+3u^{-\frac{5}{2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0
$$

Note that this a case of $\mbox{div (grad(} f))=0$

Comment: This works, but I think you are missing an edge case. Think about where this function might not be defined. (Think about the potential of a point particle in a standard Electrostatic problem)

Comment: Obviously the function is not defined for $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Then you will accept that the laplacian isn't 0 in general but only where it is defined. This is a textbook path to the delta function of the magnitude of x as you will see in any upper level physics text.

Comment: The function is not defined in the origin, and thus also its derivatives/differential operators. This is not physics.

Comment: I agree, so the accurate statement isn't that laplacian is 0, it's that the laplacian is zero everywhere except at the origin, where it is undefined. This is different from saying that $\texttt{div} (\texttt{grad}(f))=0$

Comment: @KitterCatter: I agree! But is seems a bit pedantic . :)

Comment: Except that the pedantic detail has practical consequence

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute a 'symbolic' dot product between $\nabla$ and $\nabla f$, that is:
$$\nabla \cdot \nabla f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2}$$
In your case

$$\nabla \cdot\nabla\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol x\|}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-x(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right) +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(-y(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(-z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right) = -\left(-\frac{3}{2}2x^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)-\left(-\frac{3}{2}2y^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)-\left(-\frac{3}{2}2z^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right) = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}-3(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}=3(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}-3(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}=3\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol x\|^3}-3\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol x\|^3} = 0$$

Since the function satisfies the Laplace equation $\nabla^2f =0$, it is a harmonic function.

Answer (score 1):

Using index notation the proof is more succinct:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}(x_{i}x_{i})^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[-\frac{1}{2}(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{3}{2}}2x_{i}\frac{\partial x_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{3}{2}}x_{i}\delta_{ij}\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[-(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{3}{2}}x_{j}\right]=\frac{3}{2}(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{5}{2}}2x_{p}\frac{\partial x_{p}}{\partial x_{j}}x_{j}-(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\partial x_{j}}{\partial x_{j}}=3(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{5}{2}}(x_{j}x_{j})-3(x_{k}x_{k})^{-\frac{3}{2}}=0$$